# Print specific string sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

this is my first question here.

I need to do a function that returns a specific string sequence, example:

1st call returns "a"
2nd call returns "b", 
3rd call returns  "c"
4th call returns "a"
5th call returns "a"
6th call returns "b"
7th call returns "b"
8th call returns "c"
9th call returns "c" etc (sequence is a,b,c - a,a,b,b,c,c - a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c etc)

The function must return only the specific string, so if i call the function 2 times by doing "println(magicFunction());" twice, it has to return "a" on the fist call and "b" on the second one.

Here is what i tried to do in Java.

```
public class Main {

static int repetitions = 1;
static int said = 0;
static int cursor = 0;
static String[] list= {"a", "b", "c"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
        System.out.println(nextStr());
}

public static String nextStr() {

    if (said >= repetitions ) {
        cursor++;
        said = 0;
    } else {
        said ++;
    }

    if (cursor == 2 && said == repetitions ) {
        cursor = 0;
    }

    return list[cursor];
 }
}
```

Comment: What, then, is the question?

Comment: I think you need to write more expressive variable names. "Said" is very vague.

Comment: I dont get your question. You initial output sequence contradicts what you are saying afterwards. Please try to clarify.

Comment: also the instructions are unclear. Why should it repitivly print `a, a, a` when the second call should make it print `b`?

Comment: On third call what it should return and so on.. Clarify your question.

Comment: I think i clarified my question (see the edited one).
EXAMPLE: 1st call -> "a", 2nd call -> "b", 3rd call -> "c", 4th call ->"a", 5th call ->"a" etc.

Comment: So the output is : a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c?

Comment: Or abcaabbccaaabbbcccaaaabbbbcccc... ?

Comment: Your examples are contradicting each other.  In your first example it returns "b" when called the second time, and in the second it returns "a" when called the second time.  Your function cannot possibly know how many times in the future it will be called.

Comment: The output differs by the ammount of calls that i do on the function.
on 1st call -> "a", 2nd call -> "b", 3rd call -> "c", 4th call ->"a", 5th call ->"a", 6th call ->"b", 7th call -> "b", 8th call -> "c", 9th call->"c"

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @SDex essentially, I think your code is on the right track. You just need to debug it: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  You don't need SO to debug it for you.

Comment: oh, at some point you need to increment `repetitions` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will achieve what you're after.

`cursor` starts at `0` and increments by 1 iff `queried == queryLetter`.

When `queried == queryLetter`, `queried` is reset to `0`.

If `cursor == characters.length` then increment `queryLetter` by `1`.

```
public class CharSource {

    private int cursor = 0;
    private int queryLetter = 1;
    private int queried = 0;
    private char[] characters = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSource source = new CharSource();
        for (int i=0; i<40; i++) {
            System.out.println(source.get());
        }
    }

    public char get() {
        char result = characters[cursor];
        if (++queried == queryLetter) {
            if (++cursor == characters.length) {
                cursor = 0;
                queryLetter++;
            }
            queried = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yhea, this is what i wanted. i forget to do a lot of things with my "repetitions" variable

Comment: Just a note, since you may be new to Java, `++variable` increments the value by 1 prior to its use. Also using static variables in this manner is far from desirable but makes the example simpler.

Comment: @d.j.brown Nice work. Since you've pointed out the problem with statics, I've been cheeky and "upgraded" it to not use them. Hope that's OK. If OP doesn't get it, he will learn soon, and it's a better example to leave on SO for posterity.

Comment: @slim fine with me! I just tried to keep it as close to the original question as possible. Cheers for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very long stream to generate the sequence:

```
Stream<Character> stream = IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i/3).mapToObj(j -> (char)('a' + i % 3)));
```

And to print the first 100 elements:

```
stream.limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

It generates

[image: Math.floor((n + 1) * (n + 2) / 6)]
maximum number of elements, if that would not be enough, you can always switch to `LongStream`.